# Outlook sync IMAP folders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

I currently have IMAP hosting from [SolidShellSecurity, LLC](http://solidshellsecurity.com) and not Exchange if that means much. I wanted to save money and just go with IMAP because that was free over $10/mo per mail box with Exchange.

Anyway, I noticed that with Outlook it creates it's own Sent folder and Spam, Delete, ect... Is there a way to sync or replace those so that they use the IMAP folders on the IMAP server? I want to use outlook on several machines as I have many laptops and desktops but I want to also keep my mail all in the same place and not scattered all over many machines.

This is Outlook 2013

Comment: Outlook version? Maybe these will help. Tutorial for [Outlook 2010 and below](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/486) | Tutorial for [Outlook 2013](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/736)

Comment: Edited. This is 2013 :)